# error converting a const void* to some other pointer without const_cast

Tags: c++, casting, constants

The function

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    SomeDataType g1 = *(static_cast<SomeDataType*>(a));
    SomeDataType g2 = *(static_cast<SomeDataType*>(b));
    g1.firstelement < g2.firstelement ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This code returns an error saying "static cast can't cast from const void* to SomeDataType*." I use const_cast like

```
SomeDataType g1 = *(static_cast<SomeDataType*>(const_cast<void*>(a))) ;
```

to get this working. Is that a right way to do it ? Or am I missing something?  I am not understanding quite how this works.

Comment: If you want to cast away the `const` you have to use `const_cast`.

Comment: what is a static_cat?

Comment: In my experience, most cats are static (in other words, you have a typo. It amused me enough to comment instead of correcting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't feel right because it *shouldn't feel right*. Someone gave you a pointer and in the interface you promised that you would not modify it, casting away the `const` is breaking your promise (well, not really, but the type system considers that if you cast away const, is is because you want to modify the object, which *would* break your promise).

I suggest that you don't drop the `const`:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    SomeDataType g1 = *(static_cast<const SomeDataType*>(a));
    SomeDataType g2 = *(static_cast<const SomeDataType*>(b));
    return g1.firstelement < g2.firstelement ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: could not edit the typo (less than 6 characters)  

*static_cat*

should be

*static_cast*

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
const SomeDataType g1 = *static_cast<const SomeDataType *> (a);
const SomeDataType g2 = *static_cast<const SomeDataType *> (b);
```

You don't need `const_cast` here.

However I prefer this:

```
int compare(const SomeDataType &g1, const SomeDataType &g2)
{
    return g1.firstelement < g2.firstelement ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i can't change the way function is written. So i have to stick to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just convert to const SomeDataType* like this

```
SomeDataType g1 = *(static_cat<const SomeDataType*>(a));
```

Of course, doing that make a copy of the data, Instead you should do this

```
const SomeDataType& g1 = *(static_cat<const SomeDataType*>(a));
const SomeDataType& g2 = *(static_cat<const SomeDataType*>(b));
g1.firstelement < g2.firstelement ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

static_cast is not able to remove const-ness from a pointer and it is not meant to do so. Only cast able to do that is const_cast. So you have to cast in two steps just like you do. In your case you don't need the pointer to be non-const by the way. So you may simply do:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const SomeDataType* g1 = static_cast<SomeDataType*>(a);
    const SomeDataType* g2 = static_cast<SomeDataType*>(b);
    g2->GetFirstElement() - g1->GetFirstElement();
}
```

Assuming you have implemented const accessor to the field you use.

Comment: would creating a pointer inside compare not make a and b dangling pointers when the compare goes out of scope ?

Comment: Nope. You are not copying the memory referred to by a or b and also you are using bare pointers nothing fancy. Also the pointers g1 and g2 are local(not that it matters here.)

Comment: hmm, I would have expected destructor of g1 and g2 being called and messing things up when compare goes out of scope. 
But I guess I am wrong because everytime new is used, we have to use delete so .. 
cool thanks !

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const SomeDataType *g1 = static_cast<const SomeDataType*>(a);
    const SomeDataType *g2 = static_cast<const SomeDataType*>(b);
    return g1->firstelement < g2->firstelement ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: People correct me if I am wrong but this code is a blunder : 
When compare ends, g1 and g2 die out killing with it the data it contains. And then the a and b become dangling pointers with is bound to die in oblivion ??

Comment: @navderm: No, they will not die after exiting the function, because `g1` and `g2` are pointers. Pointers will be destroyed when you explicitly `delete` them.

Answer (score 0):

Use const!

```
const SomeDataType g1 = *(static_cast<SomeDataType const *>(a));
```

Since you are not going to alter `g1`, there is no need to NOT have it const.

You probably also want a `return`:

```
return  g1.firstelement < g2.firstelement ? 1 : -1;
```

Not sure if you care about g1 == g2 too?